# Android application deployment error in buildozer Python kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, ssl, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to debug and deploy a kivy android app using:

- buildoser v=1.2.0,
- python version 3.6,
- pip3 version 9.0.1,
- VMware 15,
- ubuntu version 18.04

I have also installed all packages dependency for buildozer as below:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev
pip3 install --user --upgrade cython virtualenv
sudo apt install cython
**also I install these following packages**
sudo apt install cython3
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install automake
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install libtool m4 automake
sudo apt-get install lld
then I type this command
**buildozer -v android debug**
```

after 15-20 minutes deployment it is showing following errors in the console and deployment stopped:

```
[INFO]: The requirements (certifi) don't have recipes, attempting to install them with pip
[INFO]: If this fails, it may mean that the module has compiled components and needs a recipe.
[INFO]: -> directory context /home/am-ubuntu/kiv/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build
[INFO]: -> running python3 -m venv venv
[INFO]: Upgrade pip to latest version
[INFO]: -> running bash -c source venv/bin/activate && pip install -U pip
[INFO]: Install Cython in case one of the modules needs it to build
[INFO]: -> running bash -c venv/bin/pip install Cython
Exception in thread background thread for pid 124834:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/home/am-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/am-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
handle_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/am-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/am-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

RAN: /bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

STDOUT:
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Cython
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/am-ubuntu/kiv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1231, in
main()
File "/home/am-ubuntu/kiv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
ToolchainCL()
File "/home/am-ubuntu/kiv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 688, in init
getattr(self, command)(args)
File "/home/am-ubuntu/kiv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
File "/home/am-ubuntu/kiv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 208, in build_dist_from_args
args, "ignore_setup_py", False
File "/home/am-ubuntu/kiv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 598, in build_recipes
ignore_setup_py=ignore_project_setup_py
File "/home/am-ubuntu/kiv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 778, in run_pymodules_install
), _env=copy.copy(base_env))
File "/home/am-ubuntu/kiv/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
for line in output:
File "/home/am-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 925, in next
self.wait()
File "/home/am-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 849, in wait
self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/am-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

RAN: /bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

STDOUT:
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting Cython
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing dependency issue. You can check the following youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-V-iH4MQI8&t=320s

It provides a good complete step-by-step procedure to install buildozer correctly.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct...ok I will try it and let you know whether I am successful or not asap